# Best way to display old, low resolution PC games on modern monitors?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, monitor, dos

For clarification, I'm *not* asking about getting the games to simply *work* on modern hardware/software.

A lot of old DOS games had low max resolutions. Many (like Jagged Alliance: Deadly Games) maxed out at 640x480. Modern monitors have such high PPI (pixels per inch) that playing at the native resolution puts the game into a tiny letterbox. Playing fullscreen stretches the textures out causing a pixelated mess.

Is there a good way to display these games at a good size without just getting a monitor with a lower PPI? I suspect there's no good solution but maybe something exists that's better than what I do, which is just play in a tiny window.